# Why isn't this page's background black?

Tags: html, css

What am I not seeing here?

HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></link>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS: (css/style.css)

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}
```

I already double-checked the file structure. What am I missing?

Comment: Oops. Bootstrap (which I removed from the example because I assumed it didn't modify or double up on default page attributes) was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give your `link` element a closing tag. Either leave it as `<link attributes='values'>` or make it self closing: `<link attributes='values'`**/**`>`

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Less typing if you leave the `/` off self closing tags. In HTML5 this is ok, however there are other versions of HTML and XML that require all tags to be formally closed.

link: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).

**Update**: Despite this, most browsers still render correctly when the `link` element is closed incorrectly. And that wasn't the problem here.

Comment: Also don't close `<img ...>` tags (for future references). Most tags require closing tags but very few of them don't.